# In FastAPI, how can I expand a model's output with a reverse URL lookup based on a field?

Tags: fastapi, pydantic, starlette

Let's assume I have a simple file storage in the database. The SQLAlchemy model looks like this:

```
class Blob(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    blob = deferred(Column(LargeBinary().with_variant(LONGBLOB, "mysql")))
```

The respective Pydantic model looks like this:

```
class BlobBase(sqlalchemy_to_pydantic(Blob, exclude=["blob"])):
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

There is also a FastAPI route intented for fetching single files by ID:

```
@router.get("/blob/{blob_id}")
async def get_blob(blob_id: str):
   [...]
```

And a route for fetching a list of all files:

```
@router.get("/blobs", response_model=List[BlobBase])
async def get_blobs():
    return [BlobBase.from_orm(x) for x in db.session.query(Blob).all()]
```

Now, I would like to include the resolved `get_blob` URL in each entry in `get_blobs`. Naively, I suppose this should look like this:

```
class BlobBase(sqlalchemy_to_pydantic(Blob, exclude=["blob"])):
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

    url: Optional[str]

    @validator("url")
    def make_url(cls, v, values):
        return request.url_for("get_blob", blob_id=values["id"])
```

However, I do not have access to a `request` or an `app` object in the validator, so that I cannot properly resolve the URL. NB: I do have access to the `router` object, which is an `APIRouter` for the current sub-URL, but `get_blob` in the actual application is in a different `APIRouter`, so I can't use that without jamming everything in a single file.

What is the correct way to solve this, i.e. include a resolved URL in model's output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have defined `from_orm` in the config for your model, you shouldn't have to do the manual transformation using `from_orm(x)` in your `get_blobs` view - returning the result from the query by itself should be enough.

```
@router.get("/blobs", response_model=List[BlobBase])
async def get_blobs():
    return db.session.query(Blob).all()
```

It's also suggested to use a dependency to resolve `db` for each async endpoint (there's an example in the FastAPI docs) instead of having a global-ish `db` entry.

Since the reverse URL isn't really a property of the schema itself, I think I'd go with adding a composite schema and then populate it in your view:

```
class BlobWithUrl(BaseModel):
    blob: BaseBlob  # Consider using Blob as the name instead - base indicates that it should only be inherited
    url: str


@router.get("/blobs", response_model=List[BlobWithUrl])
async def get_blobs(request: Request):
    return [
        {'url': url_for(...), 'blob': blob}
        for blob in db.session.query(Blob).all()
    ]
```

Another option is to use the strategy with manually calling `from_orm`, and then having a schema that extends `BlobBase`:

```
class BlobWithUrl(BaseBlob):
    url: Optional[str]


@router.get("/blobs", response_model=List[BlobWithUrl])
async def get_blobs(request: Request):
    blobs = []

    for retrieved_blob in db.session.query(Blob).all():
        blob = BlobWithUrl.from_orm(retrieved_blob)
        blob.url = url_for(...)
        blobs.append(blob)
    
    return blobs
```

Comment: Thanks, I think something along the lines of the second method will work for me. About your comment `Consider using Blob as the name instead`: what would be the recommendation for naming and/or importing SQLAlchemy models (called `Blob`) and Pydantic models (called `BlobBase`, with the intention to have `BlobInput` and `BlobOutput` as derived models) in same file?

Comment: I usually keep my schemas (i.e. the pydantic models) separate from my SQLAlchemy models, and then import them as BlobSchema or BlobModel if I'm going to use both in the same file; if you have separate input/output models, I postfix them as you mention. It's just that `Base` indicates that something should be inherited, when in this case you don't do that. You could also use BlobSchema as the name, since it describes the schema for information exchange, compared to the model layer in your application.